# python code error(linux , web scraping) strange error

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am trying to get some data from the NYT(New york times) articles, When I execute the following code , it gives me an error which I am not familiar with, I searched on google and went through previous answers from stackoverflow, but didn't understand my problem.
Can anyone please tell me how to solve my error.
Thanks in advance!

the code:

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
api = articleAPI('a0de895aa110431eb2344303c7105a9f')

articles = api.search( q = 'Obama', 
     fq = {'headline':'Obama', 'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']}, 
     begin_date = 20111231 )

def parse_articles(articles):
    '''
    This function takes in a response to the NYT api and parses
    the articles into a list of dictionaries
    '''
    news = []
    for i in articles['response']['docs']:
        dic = {}
        dic['id'] = i['_id']
        if i['abstract'] is not None:
            dic['abstract'] = i['abstract'].encode("utf8")
        dic['headline'] = i['headline']['main'].encode("utf8")
        dic['desk'] = i['news_desk']
        dic['date'] = i['pub_date'][0:10] # cutting time of day.
        dic['section'] = i['section_name']
        if i['snippet'] is not None:
            dic['snippet'] = i['snippet'].encode("utf8")
        dic['source'] = i['source']
        dic['type'] = i['type_of_material']
        dic['url'] = i['web_url']
        dic['word_count'] = i['word_count']
        # locations
        locations = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'glocations' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                locations.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['locations'] = locations
        # subject
        subjects = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'subject' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                subjects.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['subjects'] = subjects   
        news.append(dic)
    return(news) 

def get_articles(date,query):
    '''
    This function accepts a year in string format (e.g.'1980')
    and a query (e.g.'Amnesty International') and it will 
    return a list of parsed articles (in dictionaries)
    for that year.
    '''
    all_articles = []
    for i in range(0,100): #NYT limits pager to first 100 pages. But rarely will you find over 100 pages of results anyway.
        articles = api.search(q = query,
               fq = {'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']},
               begin_date = date + '0101',
               end_date = date + '1231',
               sort='oldest',
               page = str(i))
        articles = parse_articles(articles)
        all_articles = all_articles + articles
    return(all_articles)

Amnesty_all = []
for i in range(1980,2014):
    print 'Processing' + str(i) + '...'
    Amnesty_year =  get_articles(str(i),'Amnesty International')
    Amnesty_all = Amnesty_all + Amnesty_year

import csv
keys = Amnesty_all[0].keys()
with open('amnesty-mentions.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(Amnesty_all)
```

the error which was generated when running in the terminal:

```
rakesh-chinta@rakeshchinta-VirtualBox:~$ cd Desktop
rakesh-chinta@rakeshchinta-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ python nyt.py
Processing1980...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nyt.py", line 66, in <module>
    Amnesty_year =  get_articles(str(i),'Amnesty International')
  File "nyt.py", line 59, in get_articles
    articles = parse_articles(articles)
  File "nyt.py", line 14, in parse_articles
    for i in articles['response']['docs']:
KeyError: 'response'
rakesh-chinta@rakeshchinta-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ python nyt.py
Processing1980...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nyt.py", line 66, in <module>
    Amnesty_year =  get_articles(str(i),'Amnesty International')
  File "nyt.py", line 59, in get_articles
    articles = parse_articles(articles)
  File "nyt.py", line 14, in parse_articles
    for i in articles['response']['docs']:
KeyError: 'response'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

api.search returns a result not expected. Its code:

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()
```

So only if api "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch" returns right response and the response has correct json body, you can get your code run correctly.

Exception is KeyError, so the return object is dict like. you may want to check:

```
In [8]: print articles.keys()
Out[8]: [u'status', u'response', u'copyright']
```

and:

```
In [9]: print articles['status']
Out[9]: u'OK'
```

If not, I guess nyt api may not fill response when articles['status'] != 'OK', you may need to handle this unexpected status and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce time.sleep(1) in the loop

```
import time
```

Like this:

```
     articles = parse_articles(articles)
     all_articles = all_articles + articles
     time.sleep(1)
return(all_articles)
```

This error is because of maximum 5 requests per second limit by the API used inside the package.